# VS Code: bring up the Ctrl+Shift+P Command Pallette but without ">" in it

Tags: visual-studio-code

When you press `Ctrl + Shift + P` (or whatever you bind it to) in VS Code a Command Palette pops up. It brings up a **magical textbox** with a angle bracket `>` string in it that you can type in to access commands, like `>fold all`.

But most of the time I instead use this **magical textbox** to search for functions or objects in my code via `@function` or in all dependencies via `#function`, or just open files `myfile.py`.

So every time I press `Ctrl + Shift + P` I immediately have to follow it up with a backspace to remove angle bracket `>`, so that the string in the **magical textbox** starts with the appropriate `@` or `#` character instad of `>`.

Sadly, typing `>@function` does not search for `function`, so the angle bracket `>` has to be removed manually.

How do I get VS Code to bring up the **magical textbox** but not insert the angle character `>`?

*(Note: I know I could just write an AHK or similar macro to follow up `Ctrl + Shift + P` with a backspace, but I don't trust backspaces in a macro.)*

*Alternately, how do I access a search box with similar `@function` search behaviour? (The answer is definitely ***not*** `Ctrl + F`.)*

Comment: Just click Ctrl+P without Shift?

Comment: @Ralf: I'm not the OP, but I just tried it and it works for me on macOS! Please consider posting it as an answer. As a bonus, you'll earn rep that way.

Comment: @Ralf now I feel dumb not trying that, but yes. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look the shortcuts just type `Keyboard Shortcuts` in the command pallet (or magic textbox :D) and search for "Go to File", default it is `CTRL+P`